# Empty space at the end of SQL Server query results

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sqldatatypes

I just installed Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 to test with LINQ to SQL.

I have a table with one column of type nchar(20) and two rows: '123' and 'Test'.

If I query all the rows from that table and wrap each value with "'" I get the following:

```
'123 _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ ' ( _ is a space)

'Test _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ ' ( _ is a space)
```

SQL Server seems to be filling the unused space (because the column is a 20 byte nchar) with spaces.

What can I do to prevent this from happening?

Comment: Just to add that it is a 40 byte nchar not 20 as in your question. Unicode datatypes take double the space.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use nvarchar instead of nchar.  nchar is a fixed width field that is filled with spaces, as you're seeing.

Answer (score 2):

Change the column type to `nvarchar`.

See [nchar and nvarchar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186939.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

you need `nvarchar`, it is flexible.